# Pipeline in Spark Structured Streaming using foreachBatch

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

Can we chain multiple `foreachBatch` in Spark Structured streaming ?

Eg:

```
df.writeStream.format("parquet")
    .foreachBatch(pre_process)
    .foreachBatch(mask)
    .trigger(once=True)
    .outputMode("append")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "location")
    .start()
```

If not possible, can the function in `foreachBatch` call multiple other batch functions ?

Answer (score 0):

Wording of question a little awkward compared to example, but...

- No chaining evident if you run two such statements.
- Two `foreachBatch`es run independently.
- If you look at the manual and the examples you will see that it is about writing and write guarantees.